# Cannot compile a single (generated) .cxx file in a cmake build project

Tags: cmake

In order to speed up turnaround time I need to tell make (Makefiles generated by cmake 3.0.0) to attempt to build only a single .cxx file (generated by bison).

I'm unable to do this.
I can find many dependency entries in various depend.make but neither using make nor cmake I'm able to build only this single file. Both keep telling me:

```
hostname /directory : make -j32 vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/vc_gram.cxx.o
make: *** No rule to make target `vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/vc_gram.cxx.o'.  Stop.
hostname /directory : cmake --target vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/vc_gram.cxx.o
CMake Error: The source directory "/directory/vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/vc_gram.cxx.o" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
hostname /directory : find . -type f|xargs grep -l '\<vc_gram.cxx.o\>'
./vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc.dir/link.txt
./vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc.dir/build.make
./vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/depend.make
./vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/cmake_clean.cmake
./vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/build.make
./vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/DependInfo.cmake
./vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/depend.internal
./vc/Makefile
hostname /directory : cd vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir/
hostname /directory/vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir : make vc_gram.cxx.o
make: *** No rule to make target `vc_gram.cxx.o'.  Stop.
hostname /directory/vc/CMakeFiles/tda_vc_object_lib.dir :
```

The path name I specified for the .o file is correct -- I made certain of this.

Answer (score 0):

When calling make in the directory vc everything worked:

```
hostname /directory/vc : make vc_gram.cxx.o
```